# Cannot find 'assumeOnActorExecutor' in scope

Tags: swift, realm

After install realm i got 4 errors

I coudn't find a solution any where and here the error message: Cannot find 'assumeOnActorExecutor' in scope
See screen shot

Help please[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjvok.jpg)

After install realm i got 4 errors

Comment: Welcome to SO. The question and issue are vague. Take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, It’s a good idea to include code and errors as *text*, not links and images. Take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Lastly, go through the Realm [Getting Started](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/install/) guide.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to the same issue, but it turned out to be my Pod File configuration.

I had platform :ios, '9.0' and it needs to be platform :ios, '12.0'